# New CMD window prints: '■@' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd, windows-10

Whenever I open a new Command Prompt window it prints

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USERNAME>■@
'■@' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\USERNAME>
```

and I can't figure out where it comes from. It interferes with a C# application I'm using that tries to run `some-package --version` through a `Process` instance, and based on `processInstance.ExitCode` build the UI, but that gets interrupted due to this.

My best guess is that `cmd.exe` tries to execute something when launched but I couldn't find a `.bashrc` equivalent. I tried to remove the `Path` variables in both `User variables` and `System variables` if any
`Path` values might have pointed to a non-existing directory/file, but it still comes up.

Any ideas how I could debug this?

Comment: Type `cmd /?` into a Command Prompt window and learn about the `Autorun` feature, which might be the problem here; try opening Command Prompt with `cmd /D` to prevent `AutoRun` and check whether there is a difference…

Comment: @aschipfl `cmd /D` did make a difference and I found the problem, thanks for your help

Comment: this effect usually occurs, if a batch file (`*.bat` or `*.cmd`) is not properly encoded as "ANSI" (Notepad-nomenclature). Load it in Notepad.exe and save it again - making sure to set the encoding to ANSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `cmd /D` it did not come up, which made me look at the `AutoRun` entries in the registry which are located in:

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`
and

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

Here I found an `AutoRun` entry that I deleted which solved the problem.